# Using custom route with versioning in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I use a custom middleware to change the Path used in a request to a WebApi.

In my middleware Invoke, I have:

```
// code prior to this extracts controller name and remaining path
var newPath = $"/{version}/{controller}/ToDoItemDto/{remainingPath}"; // ToDoItemDto was inserted by me and was not in the original request
context.Request.Path = newPath;
return _next(context);
```

In my ToDoController, I have:

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
// other attributes for the controller
public class TodoController : Controller
{
// ...
  [HttpGet("TodoItemDto/{primaryId}", Name="GetTodoById")]
  public IActionResult GetById(long primaryId)
  {
      // code here...
  }
}
```

However, when I attempt to access this controller, I get an Http 405 error with the following result:

`{"error":{"code":"UnsupportedApiVersion","message":"The HTTP resource that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:1482/v1/todo/ToDoItemDto/1' does not support the API version '1'.","innerError":null}}`

I tried adding the following attribute to my `GetById()` method:

`[MapToApiVersion("1.0")]`

but that did not help.

I searched the web and found a [promising result](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/95) on the GitHub page for the versioning Api. However, I don't understand the suggested fix (using an IActionResult) in this context.

Can custom route matching be done while also using versioning? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed to add ***api*** in the route. Try it this way

```
var newPath = $"api/{version}/{controller}/ToDoItemDto/{remainingPath}";
```

Comment: such a simple omission cost me about an hour of trouble. It's always the little things. Thanks for the answer.